Which comes first curiosity or creativity
What is the causal relationship between creativity and curiosity ? Is curiosity also a drive that is ingrained in our DNA (like hungry for food and horny for sex ) ?
Are humans curiosity driven right from there birth or evolution compels us to be more curious ?

This is a very interesting question, but it's not a philosophical question. As posted here it belongs on a site for biology, pyschology or neurology. I'm voting to close it. Willing to reopen it, if you provide a motivation - an explanation of its philosophical relevance.

It's not obvious to me that one is the cause of the other. Creativity comes from needing to solve problems (like how to get food or sex). Curiosity seems independent of it, although I suppose getting an answer to something you're curious about could be a problem you use creativity to solve.

My curiosity impelled me to doing a search online to find out more about your question.  An extract from this article)

Philosopher and psychologist William James (1899) called curiosity “the impulse towards better cognition,” meaning that it is the desire to understand what you know that you do not. He noted that, in children, it drives them towards objects of novel, sensational qualities—that which is “bright, vivid, startling”.  This early definition of curiosity, he said, later gives way to a “higher, more intellectual form”—an impulse towards more complete scientific and philosophic knowledge.

A study conducted in 1903 on the behaviour of young children suggested that children progressed through four stages of development:

starting with “passive staring” as early as the second week of life, on through “curiosity proper” at around the fifth month.

The summary of the article made the following proposal:

We propose that, rather than worry about defining curiosity, it is more helpful to consider the motivations for information-seeking behavior and to study it in its ethological context.

From this, I would suggest that human curiosity is an inbuilt drive to explore, survive, and make sense of the world.  This leads to creativity as the child grows.  Our curiosity is no accident or afterthought!

According to Alfred North Whitehead (of Principia Mathematica fame) the relation is maternal rather than causal. He proposed that 'Curiosity is the mother of invention' and not Necessity, as is often claimed. Few will deny that invention is a creative endeavour.
Curiosity is associated with exploratory behaviour and playfulness. These traits have evolutionary benefits and there is tons of research with rats in mazes that have identified genes involved in exploratory behaviour. So yes, DNA.
